# Deserialize JSON into List with X++

Tags: json.net, x++

I have a problem with generic types in X++. I need to deserialize a JSON list yet everything I tried failed. Like using IEnumerables and JsonSerializer(does it find only AX classes and can't see references library classes?).

My helper class is in a C# library and I only need to get access to values inside the response JSON that are in list. How can I archive this in X++?

```
//X++
defaultException defaultException= new defaultException();
defaultException= JsonConvert::DeserializeObject(response, defaultException.GetType()); <- this gives is correct yet I cant use the values in the list

//values = FormJsonSerializer::deserializeCollection(classnum(List), response, Types::Class, 'defaultException');  

// C#
public class defaultException
{
    public MyException exception { get; set; }
}

public class MyException
{
    public string serviceCtx { get; set; }
    public string serviceCode { get; set; }
    public string serviceName { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set;}
    public string referenceNumber { get; set; }
    public List<exceptionDetailList> exceptionDetailList { get; set; }
}
public class exceptionDetailList
{
    public int exceptionCode { get; set; }
    public string exceptionDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking, but maybe one of the following links can help? 1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/x-csharp-comparison-collections 2) https://dev.goshoom.net/2017/04/generic-types-in-x-ax-7/

Comment: What does your JSON look like?  Can you [edit] your question to share the value of `response` (as text, not a screen shot)?

Comment: Well I did add the default exception class. The response looks exactly as this schema. s you can see at the end is a list with exception DetailList and Im not able to use the values inside of it using the standard deserialization. And yes, I did looked on this links yet it still didn't managed to deserialize a list so I can use the values of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. If we have another list in this list we need to recreate the enumerator in loop again and again as needed.

```
defaultException defaultException = new defaultException();
defaultException = JsonConvert::DeserializeObject(batch, defaultException.GetType());

System.Collections.IEnumerable exceptionList = defaultException.exception.exceptionDetailList;
System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator = exceptionList.GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    exceptionDetailList exceptionDetailList = new exceptionDetailList();
    exceptionDetailList =  enumerator.Current;
}
```